# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?[]' to 'int[]

Tags: c#, .net

I hahe this segment of code:

```
    private FoundContours SelectFromFoundSamples(FoundContours foundACContours, FoundContours foundFNContours, FoundContours foundBlurContours, FoundContours foundFilteredContours)
    {

        int? num = null;

        int? a = null, b = null, c = null, d = 10;


        int?[] numbers = new[] { foundACContours.Count, foundFNContours.Count, foundBlurContours.Count, foundFilteredContours.Count };

        int? max = numbers.Max();
    }
```

on this row:

```
int?[] numbers = new[] { foundACContours.Count, foundFNContours.Count, foundBlurContours.Count, foundFilteredContours.Count };
```

I get this error:

"Cannot implicitly convert type 'int?[]' to 'int[]'

Any idea how can i fix the error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Assuming your `Count` members are `int`, I get the error the other way around i.e. `... type 'int[]' to 'int?[]'`

Comment: I get that too, Rawling. Also, what are `num` and those four `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` variables doing? What is the reason to use nullable ints instead of regular ints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just change your statement

```
int?[] numbers = new[] { foundACContours.Count, foundFNContours.Count, 
                         foundBlurContours.Count, foundFilteredContours.Count };
```

To

```
int?[] numbers = new int?[] { foundACContours.Count, foundFNContours.Count, 
                             foundBlurContours.Count, foundFilteredContours.Count };
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int?[] numbers = new int?[] { foundACContours.Count, foundFNContours.Count, foundBlurContours.Count, foundFilteredContours.Count };
```